# Why does this have $rootscope.$new()?

Tags: angularjs

I am researching how to use Jasmine with Karma. I am trying to inject a scope into my controller and from somewhere I have picked up this code...

```
var scope = { message: 'hello' };

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {

    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    $controller('myController', { $scope: scope });

}));
```

The problem is that the scope is being wiped out with the line...

```
scope = $rootScope.$new();
```

So I can comment it out but I am wondering what the use of this line is for? When would I want to call `$rootscope.$new()`? I understand it is to do with isolation but I don't really get the practical applications of it.

UPDATE : As Tim points out below it is a problem because I have declared my own scope. So I can modify the code to be ....

```
var scope;

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {

    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    scope.message = 'hello';

    $controller('myController', { $scope: scope });

}));
```

And that works more like expected, but I am still wondering what the best approach is? What is `$rootscope.$new()` even for?

Comment: `The problem is the scope is being wiped out with the line` I'd think the actual 'problem' is that you *defined* your own `var scope`

Comment: Okay that makes sense now you say. With that in mind which is the best approach?

Comment: Why don't you just use Yeoman and let it setup your jasmine/karma configuration?

Comment: I can't understand what the problem is. You need to instantiate your controller. Your controller needs a scope as argument. So you create a scope, and pass it as argument to your controller. And if your controller expects the scope to already have a message attribute (which seems strange to me), then you add the message attribute before passing the scope to the controller.

Comment: I don't understand why there are downvotes on this question. It asks what the practical applications of $rootscope.$new() is. No one has answered that directly.

Answer (score 14):

`$rootScope.$new` creates a new instance of `$rootScope.Scope` that inherits from `$rootScope`. In other words, it creates a new child scope of `$rootScope`.

The reason you might use it in tests (such as the one you posted), is because your other alternative is to use `$rootScope` itself. Doing so might create a mess since it might be used all over the place.

I consider as best practice to create (and destroy afterwards) a new scope for each test case.

Here's your example rewritten to what I consider a best practice:

```
describe('myModule', function() {

    var $rootScope;

    beforeEach(module('myModule'));

    beforeEach(function() {
        inject(function(_$rootScope_) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        });
    });

    describe('myController', function() {

        var $scope;

        beforeEach(function createChildScopeForTheTest() {
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        });

        afterEach(function disposeOfCreatedChildScope() {
            $scope.$destroy();
        });

        it('tests something', function() {
            $scope.message = 'hello';

            $controller('myController', { $scope: $scope });

            expect($scope.something).toEqual('world');
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I like this example. One issue though, I get an error if I try to destroy the scope in an afterEach block. Seems that the scope is already cleaned up and destroyed at that point.

Comment: I'm using it in all my tests, of which I have over 10000. I never ran into this problem. It might be due to something else you're doing in your test. Post some code if you want help fixing that :-)

Answer (score 3):

Scopes in angular are nested in parent child relationships, all deriving from a single parent `$rootScope`

This is how angular creates the `$scope` that gets injected into your controller so it creates the same experience when you are unit testing your controller.

This is especially useful if you are doing anything in your controller which requires you to call $apply rather than you having to mock that out as well.